# .net split string after the second double quote

Tags: .net

In C# or vb.net, how do you split the following line after the second double quote?  I have tried a lot of different things, but so far nothing has seemed to work.

"foo" bar

Result:

"foo"

Bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to call:

```
int firstIndex = str.IndexOf('\"');
```

to get the zero-based index of the first occurrence of the " (and fail if not found, i.e. if return value is -1).
Then, use

```
int secondIndex = str.IndexOf('\"', firstIndex + 1);
```

to find the index of the second occurrence. Fail again if not found.

Finally, split in the middle:

```
String str1 = str.Substring(0, secondIndex + 1); // until the second "
String str2 = str.SubString(secondIndex + 1); // all the rest
```

Comment: @DannyBoy Feel free to click on the checkmark next to the post that resolve your questions.